# Cocoa - resize window to full screen. Dual display

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fullscreen, osx-yosemite

I'm try resize window for two display.

On yosemite much depends on the `[NSScreen screensHaveSeparateSpaces]` - "Displays have separate Spaces" setting.

If `screensHaveSeparateSpaces` is set to `NO`, I can resize `NSWindow` to all screens, and set `[window setLevel:CGShieldingWindowLevel()]`, and this will work.

But if `screensHaveSeparateSpaces` is set to `YES`, I only see half of the window. I'm trying:

```
NSDictionary *opts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSFullScreenModeAllScreens,
       nil];

NSView *view = [window contentView];
[view enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:opts];

NSRect frame = [view.window frame];
frame.size.width *= 2;
[view.window setContentSize:frame.size];
```

`NSView` resize to all screen this is true, but `NSView` fills my left-hand primary display - the secondary (right hand) display stays black.

How can I resize `NSView` to fullscreen (dual display) if `screensHaveSeparateSpaces` is returning `YES`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. A window exists in one space only. If each screen has a separate space, then you can't have one window on both screens. Your best bet would be to try to fake it by having two windows, one in each space, but I'm not even sure that would be possible. Assuming you can even have an app with windows in multiple spaces, it'd be non-trivial to try and keep the two windows in sync with each other.

Comment: Then why NSView resize to all screen and paint only one display? that is strangely

Comment: NSViews are "abstract" things. You can make an NSView as big or small as you want. It can be in a window's view hierarchy or not. It's just a data structure.